# SML record subset and update

Tags: sml

Is there an more straight forward way (and less error prone due to maintenance and amount of editing involved), to achieve the same as below, that is: 1) getting a subset of the elements of a record, given the names list of members of interest, 2) and updating a record from a subset record, using the names of the subset record?

```
val r = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5}
val s = {b = #b r, c = #c r, d = #d r}
val r = {a = #a r, b = #b s, c = #c s, d = #d s, e = #e r}
```

What I expect, could look like this:

```
val r = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5}
val s = #(b, c, d) r
val r = r / s
```

As Sebastian Paaske Tørhol said, one can extract part of a record this way:

```
val {b, c, d, ...} = r
```

Unfortunately, this does not bind the subset to a single name, as this, as an example, does not work:

```
val s = {b, c, d, ...} = r
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. There once was a proposal for more extensive record operations ([Functional record extension and row capture](http://successor-ml.org/index.php?title=Functional_record_extension_and_row_capture)), as part of the short-lived successor ML effort. With that, you could have written, e.g.,

```
val r = {a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5}
val {a, e, ... = s} = r
val t = {a = a+1, e = e-1, ... = s}
```

Unfortunately, nobody ever implemented it in a real compiler.

Comment: There's something related to functional records types and subtypes, named System F<: : [System F‑sub (en.wikipedia.org)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F-sub) and [Subtyping (en.wikipedia.org)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). May be worth to investigate.

Comment: Unfortunately, subtyping puts a whole new dimension of complexity and problems into a language, especially when combined with polymorphism, like in F-sub and extensions. It has plagued OO type systems for decades, and you usually don't want that in functional languages. A nicer alternative is row polymorphism, which at least allows for practical type inference.

Comment: What has plagued OO, is lack of real formalisation and formal methods: it did not stopped at the points it was not able to properly handle. Otherwise, I agree with you, if that's more complex, safety is more complex to implement too (but not impossible, if I'm not wrong, this logic is sound). Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Hm, there have been plenty of formalisations. But subtyping is a rabbit hole -- look e.g. at Abadi & Cardelli, or look at Scala for how complex it gets. Some versions of F-omega-sub are already undecidable. And all that for a fairly weak increase in expressive power (compared to parametric polymorphism).

Comment: I may be not really understanding what sub‑typing is formally.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pattern-matching to extract relevant parts of records:

Example:

```
val question = { title = "SML record subset and update",
                 author = "Hibou57",
                 tags = ["SML"] }

val { title = t, tags = ts, ... } = question
```

This binds title into `t` and tags into `ts`.

You can also simply omit the names, if you so desire:

```
val { title, tags, ... } = question
```

This binds the title to `title` and tags to `tags`.

As far as updating goes, Standard ML sadly doesn't have a nice way to update records without explicitly having to set every field.

Comment: I was not aware pattern matching could be used this way with records. Thanks for the hint. I will wait before selecting this answer, just to wait for if ever someone happily has an idea for the update part.

Comment: How is this “...” named? I've never seen it before, and it seems required, not just a place‑holder in your snippet. An issue is: although this extracts part of a record, this cannot bind this subset to a single name.

Comment: Answering myself: the “…” is just named after its common name, that is, ellipsis (SML does not give it any dedicated name).